# Received no confirmation from editor of article receipt

Tags: publications, journals, email, editors

I submitted an article to an academic journal about a week ago (not through a website but directly to an editor's email) but received no confirmation of receipt.  What is proper protocol -- time wise etc. -- for sending a followup email asking for confirmation of receipt?

Comment: Is submission via email the required way to submit a paper to this journal?

Comment: dwoz, Thank you; this is very helpful. Matthias, Yes, the journal requests submissions be sent directly by email w/attachment. Any further input/advice on the matter would be greatly appreciated. P.S. - I'm the original poster (John); once I registered the site began showing me as user41530.

Comment: How did you find out about the editor's email address? From their web site?

Answer (score 2):

10 days if you're losing sleep over it, two weeks, otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's the beginning of a semester just now...lots of folks will be navigating very tight schedules.

The answer to your question however depends a lot on the size and publication frequency of your journal, and the nature of your submission.  Put simply, the larger the publication and/or paper, the longer you should give the editor to reply.  Also if it's an infrequent publication schedule, likely the editor doesn't wade through the pile of submissions on a "crisp" pace.

If it's a well-regarded journal, there may simply be too many submissions for an editor to individually acknowledge them all.